# Why does CloudFront returns "Bad request", when calling AWS API Gateway GET method with JSON HTTP body?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-cloudfront

Why can't I call my AWS API Gateway REST API using a `GET` request with an `application/json` HTTP body? CloudFront returns an error:

> "Bad request".

The `GET` method is configured with proxy integration for the Lambda backend, so should just proxy the request through.

However, calling the `POST` method, with the same headers and HTTP body, yields a result.

[image]

```
$ curl -XGET --json '{"n": 5}' -H 'Authorization: Bearer foo' -H 'x-gateway-authorization: Bearer bar' 'https://a5t0qb2tfg.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/fib'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         git:(main|✚18…7
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: I4wmI1bt3ddj5uScRwkIU-ONFAiyQCZoYm3BIYMH6LR5QHpK1cM2aw==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>%
$ curl -XPOST --json '{"n": 5}' -H 'Authorization: Bearer foo' -H 'x-gateway-authorization: Bearer bar' 'https://a5t0qb2tfg.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/fib'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        git:(main|✚18…7
{"result": 5, "job_id": "55dc052c-2b08-486e-87b6-462abcf24e96"}%
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the title mentions that you are using Cloudfront, you may be hitting a [Cloudfront limitation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustom-get-body).

> If a viewer GET request includes a body, CloudFront returns an HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden) to the viewer.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I opt out of using CloudFront? I use the `aws_apigateway.RestApi` class from the AWS CDK